# For loop queryset from inline model

Tags: python, django-models

have a model and and inline model..
I need to create a queryset which retrieves data from the inline model and returns a for loop in a template..Looks like my code is not working though..can anyone help?

```
class Account(models.Model):
    uuid = ShortUUIDField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    address_one = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.name

class Rates(models.Model):
     airline = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, verbose_name= 'AIRLINE')
     dest = models.CharField(max_length=3,blank=True,verbose_name= 'DEST')

     name= models.ForeignKey (Account, default = False, related_name="rates")
         def __str__(self):
        return self.airline

My for loop should retrieve all rates in case account name is XXX

def rates_acc(request, account):
    account = Account.objects.get(name = xxx)
    rates = [x for x in account.rates.all()]
    context = {

        'rates': Account.objects.filter (name__name__icontains = 'xxx'),
       }
    return render(request,'accounts/account.html',context)
```

Comment: I dont understand why the view gets account patameter- you dont do anything with it. The problem with your code is the .filter(), the 'name' field in the Account model is not a foreignkey. So you cant use the__ notation. If I understand, you should change it to Rates.objects.filter(..) instead. If not, Please explain what are the records you want to query

Answer (score 1):

> My for loop should retrieve all rates in case account name is XXX

Then this:

```
'rates': Account.objects.filter(name__name__icontains='xxx)
```

Should be like this

```
'rates': Rates.objects.filter(name__name='XXX')
```

OR if you want to get all rates where account name contains XXX

```
'rates': Rates.objects.filter(name__name__icontains='XXX')
```